# Ashen / pallid / sallow / pale (/ livid)

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I have these words in my spaced repetition system (Anki). However, when I am trying to guess the translation from my mother tongue, I always guess one of the other three.

Looking for pictures on google I found that they showed very little difference among these. Are they completely synonymous? Can they be used interchangeably?

***Livid*** seems to indicate more  bluish or reddish tones, when talking about an angry person. The other three however all seem to be about *feeling sick* and *looking yellowish, whitish*.

Comment: You left out 'wan'.

Comment: They are extremely similar and one would be hard pressed to definitively distinguish any of them (aside from livid, which doesn't belong).

Comment: Pale or pallid is a paler or whitish **shade** of normal colour; ashen (greyish) and sallow (yellowish) are abnormal **colours**

Comment: My instinct is that 'sallow' refers to a person's usual complexion (and 'pale' can as well), while the others describe a temporary appearance due to illness or emotion.